# How to get Grunt-Contrib-Copy to copy files/directories relative to given source path

Tags: javascript, copy, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

First time using this task and what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

copy all directories/files from `src/js/bower_components/*` to `build/assets/js/vendor/`

I've tried using `cwd` property but it doesn't work at all when I use it.. I've set it to: `src/js/bower_components/`

*From src*

```
.
├── Gruntfile
└── src
    └── js
        └── bower_components
            └── jquery
```

*I currently get:*

```
.
├── Gruntfile
└── build
    └── assets
        └── js
            └── vendor
                src
                └── js
                    └── bower_components
                        └── jquery
```

*What I'd like*

```
.
├── Gruntfile
└── build
    └── assets
        └── js
            └── vendor
                └──jquery
```

Here's my current grunt task

```
copy: {
  main: {
    src: 'src/js/bower_components/*',
    dest: 'build/assets/js/vendor/',
    expand: true,
  }
},
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've set up an example project with tree like this:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── package.json
└── src
    └── js
        └── foo.js
```

Using the below Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    copy          : {
      foo : {
        files : [
          {
            expand : true,
            dest   : 'dist',
            cwd    : 'src',
            src    : [
              '**/*.js'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
    grunt.task.run('copy');
  });

};
```

This gave me this structure:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── dist
│   └── js
│       └── foo.js
├── package.json
└── src
    └── js
        └── foo.js
```

When I had changed `cwd` so that the Gruntfile read:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    copy          : {
      foo : {
        files : [
          {
            expand : true,
            dest   : 'dist',
            cwd    : 'src/js',
            src    : [
              '**/*.js'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
    grunt.task.run('copy');
  });

};
```

I got this dir structure:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── dist
│   └── foo.js
├── package.json
└── src
    └── js
        └── foo.js
```

So it seems like `cwd` does what you need. Maybe you left `src` at `src/js/bower_components/*` when setting `cwd` to `src/js/bower_components`? In that case, `src` should read something like `**/*.js`, but depending on what you really need.

Comment: Its worth noting that grunt-contrib-copy copies files one at a time when using the **/* pattern, which is *extremely slow*. You're probably better off with a different plugin for large file hierarchies.

Comment: This gives me: Running "build" task
Warning: Task "copy" not found. Use --force to continue.

Comment: you can add flatten:true if you want them all to be in the same destination folder